# Not able to recognize a table variable in ssis sp

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, execute-sql-task

I have created a variable in ssis called `Vpop_summary_table`.

I have used this variable in a sql statement.

my variable

> Vpop_summary_table

is expected to give value

> [dbo].[2019-02-02_pop_table]

It is fine in ssis.

```
DECLARE @Vpop_summary_table VARCHAR(100)


    SET  @Vpop_summary_table= ?
    SELECT 
          ,[Age Range]
          ,[Gender]
         ,[2023 Population]
     INTO [@Vpop_summary_table]
      FROM [dbo].[2018_Population_Table_CLARITAS]
```

My table is created as `[@Vpop_summary_table]` instead of `[dbo].[2019-02-02_pop_table]`

Comment: Object names (tables, columns, databases, functions, etc.) can't be referenced from variables. You will have to use Dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass table name as parameter, you have to use expressions to achieve that:

Open Execute SQL Task editor, Go To Expressions Tab, add an expression for the `SQLStatementSource` property as following:

```
"SELECT 
       [Age Range]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[2023 Population]
 INTO " + @[User::Vpop_summary_table] + "
 FROM [dbo].[2018_Population_Table_CLARITAS]"
```

More info at:

- [Common Examples of SSIS Expressions and Variables](https://codingsight.com/common-examples-of-ssis-expressions-and-variables/) *(check Working with SSIS expressions section)*

Answer (score 2):

Table names and column names need to be static.

If you want to do this create the full SQL and then use sp_executesql to execute it although in terms of good practices having a table in a variable doesn't look so great...